# Need to convert data (byte value into hex and hex characters as ASCII characters)

Tags: c, microcontroller, pic, data-conversion, mplab

Working:
I am reading a byte from memory (EEPROM/FLASH etc) and then i want to send this byte to computer not as actual value but as a ascii characters of its hex value.
e.g i read 160 from memory, which is 0xA0 in hex, now i want to send this number not as 160 but as 'A' and '0' (which are 0x41 and 0x30),
for this i am using this type of c code in MPLAB IDE,

```
    //Here is the code for Parity:
    uint8_t unAddParitytoByte(uint8_t unByte)
    { 
           uint8_t unNumberofOnes = 0;
           for(uint8_t unI = 0x80; unI ; unI>>=1)
           {
                 if((unByte & unI) != 0)
                {
                     unNumberofOnes++;
                }
          }
          if((unNumberofOnes%2) == 0)
          {
                  return unByte;
          }
          else
          {
               return (unByte|BIT7);
          }
    }
    void vSendByteToSoftware(uint8_t unDataByte)
    {
        uint8_t unTemp = 0, unHalfByte = 0;
        unTemp = (unDataByte >> 4) & 0x0F;
        unHalfByte = unReturnASCII(unTemp);
    /*Ignore vSerialTransmitCharacter(); as it transmit through uart and unAddParitytoByte(); to add 8th bit parity*/
        vSerialTransmitCharacter(unAddParitytoByte(unHalfByte)); 
        unBCCByte ^= unAddParitytoByte(unHalfByte);
        unTemp = unDataByte & 0x0F;
        unHalfByte = unReturnASCII(unTemp);
        vSerialTransmitCharacter(unAddParitytoByte(unHalfByte));
        unBCCByte ^= unAddParitytoByte(unHalfByte);
    }
    uint8_t unReturnASCII(uint8_t unNibble)
    {
         uint8_t unChar = 0;
         switch(unNibble)
         {
            case 0:
                 unChar = '0';
                 break;
            case 1:
                 unChar = '1';
                 break;
            case 2:
                 unChar = '2';
                 break;
            case 3:
                 unChar = '3';
                 break;
            case 4:
                 unChar = '4';
                 break;
            case 5:
                 unChar = '5';
                 break;
            case 6:
                 unChar = '6';
                 break;
            case 7:
                 unChar = '7';
                 break;
            case 8:
                 unChar = '8';
                 break;
            case 9:
                 unChar = '9';
                 break;
            case 10:
                 unChar = 'A';
                 break;
            case 11:
                 unChar = 'B';
                 break;
            case 12:
                unChar = 'C';
                break;
            case 13:
                unChar = 'D';
                break;
            case 14:
                unChar = 'E';
                break;
            case 15:
                unChar = 'F';
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return unAddParitytoByte(unChar);
    }
    vSendByteToSoftware(unReadBytesfromTargetFlash());
```

I hope this is understandable.
Problem:
My concern is that i have a controller with frequency 3.6864MHz and i have to perform this operation on almost 1M bytes or more, so its a lot time consuming.

**I was wondering if there is advance and fastest approach to this process for every single byte which can make my operation pretty fast?**

Note:(Baud rate is 115200 which is quite fast and i want speed in processing bytes rather than time to send them.)

Comment: IIRC, it takes the PIC four clock cycles to execute an instruction, so if you want to send at 115200 characters per second, you only have a budget of 8 instructions per character. That's fairly tight, especially if you're calculating parity and stuff, which it seems that you do (although you haven't posted that particular piece of code). If you want to fulfill this, then this might be the time to switch to hand-written assembly instead of trying to massage the compiler into doing the right thing.

Comment: Why do you need to send it in this form?

Comment: Its the demand of software to which i am trying to communicate..

Comment: Added the code for parity

Comment: Would it work if i increase the Fosc speed. It might reduce some time but i don't think that's a neat solution??

Comment: I suppose you are already using the available optimization options in the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Each half-byte has sixteen possible values which are sequential and start with zero.  This is ideal for a lookup table.

```
    uint8_t const ascii_hex[16] = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'};

    void vSendByteToSoftware(uint8_t unDataByte)
    {
        uint8_t unTemp = 0, unHalfByte = 0;
        unTemp = (unDataByte >> 4) & 0x0F;
        unHalfByte = ascii_hex[unTemp];
    /*Ignore vSerialTransmitCharacter(); as it transmit through uart and unAddParitytoByte(); to add 8th bit parity*/
        vSerialTransmitCharacter(unAddParitytoByte(unHalfByte)); 
        unBCCByte ^= unAddParitytoByte(unHalfByte);
        unTemp = unDataByte & 0x0F;
        unHalfByte = ascii_hex[unTemp];
        vSerialTransmitCharacter(unAddParitytoByte(unHalfByte));
        unBCCByte ^= unAddParitytoByte(unHalfByte);
    }
```

**Update**:
Since the characters you are transmitting are limited to the set of sixteen, you can precalculate the parity for these sixteen characters and then use a lookup table to get the parity value.  (Please double check whether I've done the parity calculations correctly.)

```
uint8_t const ascii_hex[16] = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'};
uint8_t const ascii_hex_with_parity[16] = { 0x30, 0xB1, 0xB2, 0x33, 0xB4, 0x35, 0x36, 0xB7, 0xB8, 0x39, 0x41, 0x42, 0xC3, 0x44, 0xC5, 0xC6};

void vSendByteToSoftware(uint8_t unDataByte)
{
    uint8_t unTemp = 0, unHalfByte = 0;
    unTemp = (unDataByte >> 4) & 0x0F;
    unHalfByte = ascii_hex[unTemp];
/*Ignore vSerialTransmitCharacter(); as it transmit through uart and unAddParitytoByte(); to add 8th bit parity*/
    vSerialTransmitCharacter(unAddParitytoByte(unHalfByte)); 
    unBCCByte ^= ascii_hex_with_parity[unTemp];
    unTemp = unDataByte & 0x0F;
    unHalfByte = ascii_hex[unTemp];
    vSerialTransmitCharacter(unAddParitytoByte(unHalfByte));
    unBCCByte ^= ascii_hex_with_parity[unTemp];
}
```

Comment: Does this Lookup table works faster than calling a function with switch? i think it might save the time of call and return call time..uint8_t const ascii_hex[16] = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'};

Comment: Thanks for the single piece of code..as i am beginner in programming, so i was doing it the long way using functions or switches..
Your code does simplify my code and it is easy to comprehend..

Comment: I believe it's very likely that this lookup table method is faster than the function/switch method.  But to prove or quantify it you'd have to either statically analyze the assembly instructions generated by the compiler or dynamically profile the executable code.  I also agree that the lookup table is simple and easy to understand, which is an added bonus.  [Profiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)) is something you should consider when trying to speed up your code.  Profiling can help to identify the portions of code that will be most effective to focus on.

Comment: @BetaEngineer You can replace your parity function with another lookup table.  See my updated answer.